# gtkmm3.0 and Css :active state selector for GtkButton state not applying changes

Tags: c++, css, gtkmm, gtkmm3

So I'm new with GUI development and I'm just implementing a user interface with C++ on a Raspbian OS using Gtkmm3.0 (GTK wrapper for c++).
I'm trying to apply custom design to a button with CSS through a Gtk::CssProvider which works perfectly.

```
css = Gtk::CssProvider::create();
css->load_from_path("css/theme.css");
auto ctx_mnew_session = mnew_session.get_style_context();
ctx_mnew_session->add_provider(css,GTK_STYLE_PROVIDER_PRIORITY_USER );
ctx_mnew_session->add_class("th-button");
ctx_mlast_session->context_save();
```

my th-button is a css defined class like this:

```
.th-button 
{
    background-color:#000000;
    color:#ffffff;
    border:solid 2px #ffffff;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
.th-button:active
{
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#000000;
}
```

The design applies perfectly but does not take in consideration the active state. It doesn't matter if I press on the button or not, the design does not change although it is said in the Gtk+ reference that the :active selector is handled.

> Another use of pseudo-classes is to match widgets depending on their state. The available pseudo-classes for widget states are :active, :hover :disabled, :selected, :focus, :indeterminate, :checked and :backdrop. In addition, the following pseudo-classes don't have a direct equivalent as a widget state: :dir(ltr) and :dir(rtl) (for text direction), :link and :visited (for links) and :drop(active) (for highlighting drop targets). Widget state pseudo-classes may only apply to the last element in a selector.

Does this make any sense to you?

Config: Raspbian OS on raspberry pi 4 / GTKmm 3.24.0

My widget architecture

- MainWindow::Window
- - MainFrame::Box
- - - mnew_session::Button
- - - css::CssProvider